# Run map reduce for all keys in collections - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

i am using  map reduce in mongodb to find out the number of orders for a customer like this

```
db.order.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit (this.customer,{count:1})
    },
    function(key,values){
        var sum =0 ; 
        values.forEach(
            function(value) {
                sum+=value['count'];
            }
        ); 
        return {count:sum};
    },
    {
         query:{customer:ObjectId("552623e7e4b0cade517f9714")},
         out:"order_total"
    }).find()
```

which gives me an output like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("552623e7e4b0cade517f9714"), "value" : { "count" : 13 } }
```

Currently it is working for a single customer which is a key. Now i want this to run this map reduce query for all customers in order collection, and output the result for all like this single output. Is there any way through which I can do it for all customers in order?

Comment: Remove the "query". It's selecting a single customer. Without it this will reduce to one result per customer.

Comment: i removed this { query:{customer:ObjectId("552623e7e4b0cade517f9714")},
         out:"order_total"}, now its showing error Error: assert failed : need to supply an optionsOrOutString, what i have done wrong ?

Comment: yes done, my mistake i have also removed out part , Thanks a lot budddy

Comment: Well I did say remove "query" and not the whole options argument. "out" is a required key of options. So just remove "query" and it's data. Also read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/). It really is the best source for explaining things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a map/reduce for that simple task is a bit like using a (comparatively slow) sledgehammer to crack a nut. The [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) was basically invented for this kind of simple aggregation (and can do a lot more for you!):

```js
db.order.aggregate([
    { "$group":{ "_id":"$customer", "orders":{ "$sum": 1 }}},
    { "$out": "order_total"}
])
```

Depending on your use case, you can even omit the `$out` stage and consume the results directly.

```js
> db.orders.aggregate([{ "$group":{ "_id":"$customer", "orders":{ "$sum": 1 }}}])
{ "_id" : "b", "orders" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "a", "orders" : 3 }
```

Note that with very large collections, this most likely is not suitable, as it make take a while (but it should still be faster than a map/reduce operation).

For finding the number of orders of a single customer, you can use a simple query and use the [cursor.count()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) method:

```js
> db.orders.find({ "customer": "a" }).count()
3
```

Comment: tried the same thing but it is giving empty result , what can be the cause

Comment: @user29578 Please add some example documents and use the edit button to add them to your question...

Comment: i removed this {"$out":"order_total"}, and it worked, dont why :)

Comment: @user29578 Well, works on my machine ;) You should investigate this, however, using the documentation…

Comment: one more thing if you can help, if i dont want to run on whole order collection , instead only on the order records which i get from this query  db.delivery.find({"status":"DELIVERED"},{order:1}).pretty()
, which gives me { "order" : ObjectId("551be725e4b0d253d957ca62") }
{ "order" : ObjectId("551c5381e4b0df29878547e1") }
{ "order" : ObjectId("551c8f8ae4b0ab335af6ab91") }
{ "order" : ObjectId("551ca7ede4b0ab335af6ab95") }
{ "order" : ObjectId("551cb00fe4b0ab335af6ab98") }
{ "order" : ObjectId("551cbe20e4b0df29878547ed") }

Comment: That is a different question, and please ask a new one. Also, never post code in comments (it is hard to read), but add it to your question when it is directly related.

Comment: Can you check this link , may be the question is clear now , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338553/mongodb-aggregate-query-on-specific-records-instead-of-collection