# Mongodb aggregate query on specific records instead of collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am using the aggregate query to find all orders for all customers using this query

```
> db.orders.aggregate([{ "$group":{ "_id":"$customer", "orders":{ "$sum": 1 }}}])
{ "_id" : "b", "orders" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "a", "orders" : 3 }
```

but now instead of running this query on all orders records , i just want to run it on specific set of orders , which is returned by this query

```
   db.delivery.find({"status":"DELIVERED"},{order:1}).pretty() ,
```

which gives me

```
{ "order" : ObjectId("551c5381e4b0df29878547e1") } 
{ "order" : ObjectId("551c8f8ae4b0ab335af6ab91") } 
{ "order" : ObjectId("551ca7ede4b0ab335af6ab95") } 
{ "order" : ObjectId("551cb00fe4b0ab335af6ab98") } 
{ "order" : ObjectId("551cbe20e4b0df29878547ed") }
....and few more records
```

how can i achieve this ,help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator to filter the documents getting into your pipeline.

Get the list of order ids (to use in the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline with **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)**) by using the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** cursor's **[`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** method:

```
var orderIds = db.delivery.find({"status": "DELIVERED"}).map(function(d){return d.order;});
db.orders.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": orderIds } } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$customer", "orders": { "$sum": 1 } } }
])
```

---

For MongoDB 3.2, use the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator which does a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing.

The following example shows how you can run the aggregation operation on the `orders` collection joining the documents from `orders` with the documents from the `delivery` collection using the field `order` from the `delivery` collection:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "delivery",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "order",
            "as": "delivery_orders"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "delivery_orders.status": "DELIVERED" } },    
    { "$group": { "_id": "$customer", "orders": { "$sum": 1 } } }
])
```

Comment: May be my question is not clear , this query db.orders.aggregate is being run on all records in orders collection , but i want this aggregrate query to run on only the order records i am getting from this db.delivery.find({"status":"DELIVERED"},{order:1}).pretty()  ,

Comment: @user29578 My apologies, I had not seen you were querying from another collection. Updated answer.